# how should I create the path of templateUrl property in Angular ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

Please, help!

I'm trying to figure out why the chrome console returns me that it can't find my "home.html" template `GET http://localhost:3000/home.html 404 (Not Found)`.
I'm afraid that I'm not setting correct the path of "templateUrl" property.

Here is my folder structure:

```
app.js
bin/
node_modules/
package.json
public/
---------javascript/
-------------------angularApp.js
routes/
views/
----------index.ejs
----------home.html
```

and this is my config code(located in angularApp.js)

```
angular.module('supervisor', ['ui.router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home".html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    }
])
```

I also tried different paths like "../../home.html" but with no success. If I use inline template it's working(`<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">Hello!</script>`).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear you're using express to serve your application. Express is a server side framework, while angular is a client side framework. You shouldn't mix the 2 code bases. Everything you use in angular should be served as static resources. You're very likely serving your public folder as static routes. So most likely you need to modify your structure like so (how I would structure it):

```
public
--app
----scripts
------angularApp.js
----views
------home.html
```

Then your template url should be `'/app/views/home.html'`

Comment: Hi @Vadim, Thank you for the answer, you broken my 6h of continuous debugging. I followed the instructions from the popular https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/mean-stack-tutorial/ course and I fall in the hole. They are giving as instance only inline template and this can be dramatic for a beginner like me, when he will try to use separated template files instead of inline templates, because the structure seems to be different.
Thank you again, you saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

MVC by default protects the view folder.

Add the HTMLHandler line to the views\web.config when using angular routing and you want your templates in the views folder:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="HTMLHandler" path="*.html" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Also see this [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/25/aspnetmvc-block-view-access.aspx/) for more info regarding ViewHandlers.