# templateURL in ui-router using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I generate a express project with ejs views engine.

I'm trying to set a templateURL for my home views, but it always feedback a 404 error.

Here are my codes.

In my public/javascripts/angularApp.js

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve:{
            postPromise:['posts', function(posts){
                return posts.getAll();
            }]
        }
    })
```

And in views/index.ejs

```
<div class="row container"> 
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

In views/home.html

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
</div>
```

Please help me for this problem.
thanks alot~

Comment: What URL is it requesting and what should it actually be? Maybe it should be `templateUrl: 'views/home.html'`?

Comment: @Phil I've tried that before, but still didn't work

Comment: Ok, so about my question...

Comment: I send a URL request localhost:3000/#/home

Comment: No, for the template. You said you're getting a 404 error but for what URL and what should it actually be?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your question.
Could u plz check my github repository ?
https://github.com/swarchen/MEAN_Flapper_News
really grateful for your patient

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in [how-should-i-create-the-path-of-templateurl-property-in-angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107691/how-should-i-create-the-path-of-templateurl-property-in-angular-ui-router) if using express. Then `home.html` must be inside the public folder, eg:

```
public

|--app

  |--views

     |--home.html
```

and the route would be:

```
...
templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
...
```